# Is it possible to set up a redirection rules outside Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails application and it is working great. For some specific page I would like to redirect it to some other page when a user requests that page, but what I want is to do a redirection `outside` Rails code, so the settings ,at the end, would have to be outside rails code itself. 
There could be a htaccess file to modify as an outside file to redirect to some other page, but I haven't done that so far with rails.

So, the questions is - Is that possible?

Comment: What is "to do a redirection outside Rails code"?

Comment: I don't want to make any changes in the Rails code itself to make a redirection. Is there a way to do that outside a Rails code? That is what I have meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the request before it hits Rails app. For example you can create a rewrite rule in a configuration of HTTP server you're using (nginx, apache, etc).

See these links:

- [How to redirect in apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064205/how-to-redirect-in-apache)
- [How to redirect a url in NGINX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294481/how-to-redirect-a-url-in-nginx)

If you don't have access to your server configuration (e.g. you're on Heroku) you can use `refraction` gem (https://github.com/joshsusser/refraction). It is a middleware, so in fact you're putting this redirection logic inside Rails, but at least it does not hit your controllers.

Comment: Thanks Michail. This is what I needed! :) right to the point :)

Comment: p.s. nice styling with bulleted list ;)

Answer (score 0):

Rails allows for external URL's in [`redirect_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to), so you can do something like:

```
redirect_to "http://www.example.com/interesting_page"
```

If that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks zwippie, but is there a way to define redirection rules outside rails application, like defining a `htaccess` or something like that on web-site that are using rails